# Roslyn - Rewrite extension method invocation to full qualified format

Tags: c#, roslyn

How can I rewrite an invocation of an extension method to the full qualified format, that doesn't need a using anymore?

For example.

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.Prop)
```

should become

```
System.Collections.Generic.Enumerable.OrderBy(list, x => x.Prop)
```

Comment: You want to rewrite **all** extension methods? Or only the LINQ ones?

Comment: All of them. I have access to the InvocationExpressionSyntax object and the method symbol.

Comment: @TWT did you try ReplaceNodes method?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I use this in a CSharpSyntaxRewriter object.
It would be nice if somebody also could have a look at this.

```cs
public override SyntaxNode VisitInvocationExpression(InvocationExpressionSyntax node)
{
    var methodInfo = _model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
    if (methodInfo != null)
    {
        var containingType = methodInfo.ContainingType;

        if (methodInfo.IsExtensionMethod)
        {
            // extension method
            var exp = node.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
            if (exp != null)
            {
                // new arguments
                var newArguments = SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList();
                newArguments = newArguments.AddArguments(SyntaxFactory.Argument(exp.Expression));
                newArguments = newArguments.AddArguments(node.ArgumentList.Arguments.ToArray());

                // new expression
                var stack = new Stack<SimpleNameSyntax>();
                stack.Push(exp.Name);
                stack.Push(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(containingType.Name));

                for (var s = containingType.ContainingNamespace; s != null; s = s.ContainingNamespace)
                {
                    if (!s.IsGlobalNamespace && s.Name != "")
                        stack.Push(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(s.Name));
                }

                // build and return
                if (stack.Count >= 2)
                {
                    var newExp = SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression, stack.Pop(), stack.Pop());

                    while (stack.Any())
                        newExp = SyntaxFactory.MemberAccessExpression(SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression, newExp, stack.Pop());

                    return node.WithExpression(newExp).WithArgumentList(newArguments);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return base.VisitInvocationExpression(node);
}
```

Comment: Only issue I see: don't forget to have your visitor invoke itself on the arguments too. Some case like x.Extension(y.Extension(42)) needs both to be rewritten.